# heatmap excluding first non-NaN record in each row

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am building heat map using seaborn. I need heatmap to start from the second value in each row. And this second value is not a fixed column. How to achieve that. This is the code I am using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
sns.set(font_scale=0.7)

map1=sns.heatmap(ax = ax, data = clv, annot = True, fmt='0.2f', cmap = 'Blues',linecolor='Grey',linewidth=.5, cbar=False)

st.write(fig)
```

I need heatmap on each row, but excluding the first value in each row which is not fixed.

[image]

This is sample data:

```
Column A B C D E F G H I J K L M N 
A 2.19 1.12 1.06 1.24 0.89 0.93 0.71 0.97 0.61 0.68 0.72 0.55 0.59 0.58 
B      31.05 9.31 16.48 10.77 11.60 8.43 12.33 7.89 8.49 8.61 6.95 7.23 6.97 
C            50.34 17.34 19.69 15.70 13.50 16.95 12.51 12.12 12.12 9.83 10.48 9.56 
D                  124.00 25.07 40.78 32.21 44.23 29.97 30.92 28.58 23.77 24.71 22.80 
E                         182.82 28.25 51.04 62.91 47.92 43.83 41.84 33.66 35.66 31.94 
F                                207.76 26.22 68.38 50.90 51.71 43.71 37.00 37.97 34.58 
G                                       216.92 32.33 53.02 47.19 42.77 32.44 34.16 30.33 
H                                              250.60 27.36 47.94 46.47 37.61 35.55 33.62 
I                                                     223.64 19.83 35.02 31.58 33.43 28.96 
J                                                            213.82 17.22 28.91 34.00 31.92 
K                                                                   201.36 13.90 28.63 29.06 
L                                                                          163.07 13.71 22.24 
M                                                                                177.52 11.58 
N                                                                                     1701.76
```

This is how data looks [image]

This is how it's looking right now. Heatmap is generated diagonally not in each row.

[image]

Comment: I need heatmap for each row but excluding the first value. for example in row-1: I want heat based on values from 3.3 till 1.7 in the screenshot and  the first value 6.44 not colored at all. similarly in 2nd row: heatmap for values between 27.37 and 20.50 and no color for 91.34.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to color your data without taking into account the diagonal.  You can create a mask for the diagonal, and create two heatmaps on top of each other. First a heatmap with only the diagonal, with a fixed color (or just a different colormap as the main heatmap). Then a heatmap with the rest. Seaborn will leave the masked away parts transparent.

```py
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[2.19, 1.12, 1.06, 1.24, 0.89, 0.93, 0.71, 0.97, 0.61, 0.68, 0.72, 0.55, 0.59, 0.58],
                   [np.nan, 31.05, 9.31, 16.48, 10.77, 11.6, 8.43, 12.33, 7.89, 8.49, 8.61, 6.95, 7.23, 6.97],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, 50.34, 17.34, 19.69, 15.7, 13.5, 16.95, 12.51, 12.12, 12.12, 9.83, 10.48, 9.56],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 124.0, 25.07, 40.78, 32.21, 44.23, 29.97, 30.92, 28.58, 23.77, 24.71, 22.8],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 182.82, 28.25, 51.04, 62.91, 47.92, 43.83, 41.84, 33.66, 35.66, 31.94],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 207.76, 26.22, 68.38, 50.9, 51.71, 43.71, 37.0, 37.97, 34.58],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 216.92, 32.33, 53.02, 47.19, 42.77, 32.44, 34.16, 30.33],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 250.6, 27.36, 47.94, 46.47, 37.61, 35.55, 33.62],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 223.64, 19.83, 35.02, 31.58, 33.43, 28.96],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 213.82, 17.22, 28.91, 34.0, 31.92],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 201.36, 13.9, 28.63, 29.06],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 163.07, 13.71, 22.24],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 177.52, 11.58],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1701.76]],
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N'],
                  index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N'])

sns.set() # set default seaborn style
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,12))

diagonal_mask = np.eye(len(df), dtype=bool)  # the mask is a square matrix with True on the diagonal
cmap_for_diag = sns.color_palette(['aliceblue'], as_cmap=True)  # create a one-colored colormap for the diagonal
common_keywords = dict(annot=True, fmt='.2f', linecolor='Grey', linewidth=.5, ax=ax)
# create a heatmap for the diagonal
sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap_for_diag, mask=~diagonal_mask, cbar=False, **common_keywords)
# create a heatmap for the rest of the data
sns.heatmap(df, cmap='Spectral', mask=diagonal_mask, **common_keywords)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap with special coloring for the diagonal]